# Is there a way to get the names and values of variables in scope?

Tags: variables, go, scope, stack-trace

I'm trying to write a handler for logger that sends events to sentry.
I'd like to include as context the variables in scope for easier debugging.
Is there a way to do this ( short of a WriteHeapDump ) ?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to get the names and values of variables in scope?

No.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It's short, but it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of.  You can use github.com/jwells131313/goethe to set thread-local-variables on goethe threads (special threads that have a thread id).   It's sort of frowned upon though.